# Sitecore MyGet repository access issue

Tags: nuget

Since two days `sitecore.myget.org` is down and we use `https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/` URL to restore the Sitecore packages from Nuget while deployment on server using CI/CD pipeline.

As `sitecore.myget.org` is down so build pipeline is failing, IS there any alternate approach/URL or when can expect it to up so that we can have our deployment on UAT/PROD environment.

Comment: How do you install the sxa cli with this new feed?
It was previously done like this:
npm config set @sxa:registry=https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-npm-packages/npm/
npm i -g @sxa/CLI What should the new url be?

Answer (score 3):

I have contacted to the Sitecore about the same. As per Sitecore response over support ticket:

We want to inform you that we are currently experiencing technical difficulties with our MyGet (https://sitecore.myget.org/ ) repository. As a result, there is an ongoing issue preventing the execution of both local and automated builds.

To address this situation, we recommend utilizing NuGet as an alternative during this period.
For comprehensive guidance on the workaround process, please refer to our knowledge article available at  https://sitecore.service-now.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002999.

We will keep you informed of any progress made through this page.
If there are further questions regarding this incident, please do not hesitate to raise a support case at the Sitecore Support & Self-Service Portal.

**Transition of Sitecore public feeds from MyGet to NuGet after November 2023**

Sitecore is moving its public feed from sitecore.myget.org to a different feed provider on November 30, 2023.

- The URL of the new public feed is: https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json
- The URL for the internal artifact provider is: [https://cloudsmith.io/~sitecore/repos/resources/groups/](https://cloudsmith.io/%7Esitecore/repos/resources/groups/)
- The custom NPM feed will move from https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-npm-packages to the public NPM provider https://www.npmjs.com/
  Both the original MyGet and the new public feeds are available now. After November 30, only the new NuGet and NPMJS public feeds will be available.

Sitecore strongly recommends that all customers and partners update their CI/CD processes and build scripts to use the new public feeds as soon as possible to avoid interruptions beyond November 30, 2023.