# Prolonged Unavailability of myorg: Seeking Alternative Sitecore Repositories

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api, packages, nuget

My team and I are currently engaged with a Sitecore Commerce project, and one of the key repositories we rely upon is https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-commerce-packages/api/v3/index.json. Regrettably, the myorg repository has been persistently and repeatedly offline, disrupting our work and causing concern among the team.

Given these circumstances, I am seeking advice on any other repositories that Sitecore SC might offer as potential alternatives to myorg.

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions you could provide.

Best Regards.

Comment: hope it helps you https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35620/sitecore-myget-repository-access-issue?noredirect=1#comment51106_35620

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck as Sitecore recently rushed out this page as most of the package are already migrated to the new provider (CloudSmith) planned for final go-live on the 30th November:

https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002999

> - The URL of the new public feed is: https://nuget.sitecore.com/resources/v3/index.json
> - The URL for the internal artifact provider is: [https://cloudsmith.io/~sitecore/repos/resources/groups/](https://cloudsmith.io/%7Esitecore/repos/resources/groups/)
> - The custom NPM feed will move from https://sitecore.myget.org/gallery/sc-npm-packages to the public NPM provider https://www.npmjs.com/

Thanks to Mark Cassidy for this info in Sitecore Slack.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I didn't know this. I'm going to search for the commerce packages that I'm looking for, then I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Commerce packages are still not available, Sitecore is working on it.

Comment: No worries, yeah there is a note on the above link: Sitecore Experience Commerce, Content Hub, Sitecore PowerShell and Sitecore Installation Framework packages are not yet available through the public feeds. We will update this article as soon as they are available.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the same thread which talks about the same issue and hope it would help to resolve the issue.

[Sitecore MyGet repository access issue](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/35620/sitecore-myget-repository-access-issue)